# kendo ui grid with two tables - header and data

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I was trying to use the Kendo Grid UI control.

I am using the binding from Javascript with few template columns.

When the HTML is generated it gets two tables, one for header and one for body. This becomes hard for accessibility, can someone please guide me how do I set to generate only one table with header and data in it.

Comment: Can you please provide a little more detail.

Comment: Please post some code so that we can help better

Comment: Show an example of what you are currently doing.

Comment: @veenapanakanapalli
Html Code:
       <table id="grid"> <thead><tr> <th data-field="name">Name</th><th data-field="id">Id</th></tr></thead><tbody> </tbody></table>
JS Code: 
  $("#grid").kendoGrid({height: 550, sortable: true, dataSource: { data: [{ "name": "test1", "id": "12" }, { "name": "test2", "id": "23" }] }
        });

If you check the rendered code the HTML will have  two table i.e k-grid-header and k-grid-content

Comment: @MatthiasSteinbauer  : Provided more details in prev comment

Answer (score 2):

This issue is caused by setting grid to be scrollable. Scrollable property in Kendo UI for jQuery is true by default so you need to explicitly set it false.

If you are using Kendo UI for ASP.NET MVC then you have to remove `GridBuilder`'s `.Scrollable()`  method call.